# How to merge two lists that share 1 attribute into a third one with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'd wish to create a list of the following class (List):

```
public class StatusData
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int RegisteredUsers { get; set; }
    public int Orders { get; set; }
    public decimal Import { get; set; }
}
```

This list should be filled with with information of another 2 lists: a `List<Contact>` and a `List<Purchase>`. Both classes have the following shape:

```
public class Contact
{
    public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase
{
    public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseID {get;set;}
    public int Import { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that the List should, for every day, which is the amount of Registered users, the amount of purchases and the total import of these purchases. So, in essence, both just share the Date.

However, I can't come with a good LINQ expression to create the List. One solution I considered is to retrieve all the distinct dates among the 2 lists and then iterate over them to retrieve the information I want, but I think this approach is rather "ugly". Is there any way to do what I want to do easily?

EDIT: An example of what I want would be the following:

```
Contacts
--------
Name      RegisteredDate

David     10/10/2013
Paul      09/10/2013
Gina      10/10/2013
Roger     09/10/2013
Rose      05/10/2013
Jean      07/10/2013
Mark      04/10/2013
Lisa      04/10/2013


Purchases
-----------
ID          PurchaseDate           Import
1           10/10/2013             10
2           10/10/2013             10
3           10/10/2013             20
4           04/10/2013             15
5           04/10/2013             15
6           07/10/2013             20
7           07/10/2013             2
8           07/10/2013             2


Expected result
----------------
Date          RegisteredUsers     Purchases      Import
04/10/2013    2                   2              30
05/10/2013    1                   0              0
07/10/2013    1                   3              24
09/10/2013    2                   0              0
10/10/2013    2                   3              40
```

Kind regards

Comment: A simple example would go a long way.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Can you provide the test data and desired result?

Comment: I added an example to illustrate what I want to obtain. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var contacts = new List<Contact>();
var purchases = new List<Purchase>();

var dates = contacts.Select(x => x.RegisterDate.Value)
                    .Concat(purchases.Select(x => x.PurchaseDate.Value))
                    .Distinct();

var data = from date in dates
           join c in contacts on date equals c.RegisterDate.Value into registered
           join p in purchases on date equals p.PurchaseDate.Value into purchased
           select new StatusData {
               Date = date,
               RegisteredUsers = registered.Count(),
               Orders = purchases.Count(),
               Import = purchases.Sum(x => x.Import)
           };
```

It will return `StatusData` for all days, when at least one registration **OR** one purchase was made.

Comment: This approach is interesting as it has enabled me to think about a way to include ways without any registration nor purchase. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Yeah, it's really easy to do with that approach. Just change `dates` definition to contain all days between two dates you're interested in showing data for.

Comment: I guess I'll have to modify the linq expression to allow for left outer joins for dates without any registration nor purchases.

Comment: I don't think you need any changes to get that.

Answer (score 1):

So there are several separate tasks here.  The first thing that you're doing is grouping your contacts by the registration date.  Next, you're *joining* that result to the Purchases table based on the date, aggregating count/sums on two different columns.  LINQ has a method for each of these two operations:

```
var query = from contact in contacts
    group contact by contact.RegisterDate into contactGroup
    join purchase in purchases
    on contactGroup.Key equals purchase.PurchaseDate into purchaseGroup
    select new StatusData
    {
        Date = contactGroup.Key,
        RegisteredUsers = contactGroup.Count(),
        Orders = purchaseGroup.Count(),
        Import = purchaseGroup.Sum(p => p.Import),

    };
```

Comment: It won't return record when there is a purchase at given date, but no user registration.

Answer (score 1):

This is really two separate queries with their results merged at the end.

```
var contact = from c in Contact
              group c by c.RegisterDate into c
              select new StatusData
              {
                Date = c.Key,
                RegisteredUsers = c.Count(),
                Orders = 0,
                Import = 0,
              };

var purchases = from p in Purchases
                group p by p.PurchaseDate into p
                select new StatusData
                {
                  Date = p.Key,
                  RegisteredUsers = 0,
                  Orders = p.Count(),
                  Import = p.Sum(x => x.Import),
                };

var final = from x in contact.Concat(purchases)
            group x by x.Date into x
            select new StatusData
            {
              Date = x.Key,
              RegisteredUsers = x.Sum(y => y.RegisteredUsers),
              Orders = x.Sum(y => y.Orders),
              Import = x.Sum(y => y.Import),
             };
```

Comment: This approach, as well as the one of @MarcinJuraszek, have been rather simple to understand and implement. Thank you both :)

Comment: Do you think it can be made with .Aggregate() to decrease the number of enumerations (presumably due to .Sum()) ?